# Call UserForm_Initialize from Module

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to call Private Sub UserForm_Initialize from a module.

UserForm_Initialize runs as it is supposed to. Both these methods (running in Module1) fail to execute it:

This

```
Sub Change()
    Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

returns "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined."

This:

```
Sub Change()
    UserForm.Show
End Sub
```

returns "Run-time error '424': Object required.

Here's my Userform code:
[image: Userform_Initialize]

Comment: I can't see a userform in your screenshot of the project window. Normally it's above modules. Is it in a different workbook?

Comment: What is `targetrow=cells(9999,9)` supposed to be, is there a value in the cell (9999,9)? if so then you need to say `cells(9999,9).value`, you probably need to indicate the cells() value for the additem's as well

Comment: I would recommend stepping through your code. When I have issues with a `.Show`, it's usually caused by an error in the `_Initialize()` sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be running `UserForm_Initialize` from outside the UserForm. `UserForm_Initialize` gets called when the UserForm is instantiated.

Instead, put the commands you want into a public procedure in the UserForm code module:

```
Public Sub ResetForm
    ' put stuff in here
End Sub
```

Then if you need to reset the UserForm (let's assume it's named `UserForm1`), call the code this way from a regular module:

```
Sub Change()
    UserForm1.ResetForm
End Sub
```

Comment: +1  Not only should you not run `UserForm_Initialize` from outside the user form, it is impossible to run it from outside the user form unless the form has already been initialized; adding to that,    `UserForm_Initialize` is a `Private` sub.

Comment: Actually, if you change it to a Public Sub (please don't!!), you can run `UserForm_Initialize` from outside the UserForm, and if the UserForm isn't already instantiated, it will instantiate itself to run the code. Probably not what anyone wants.

Comment: In retrospect, that makes some sense because you don't `Set` a UserForm like you would with a class - still seems odd to me.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Short answer: rather than just using `UserForm1`, you would declare a variable, `Dim fUserForm As UserForm1` and then set it, `Set fUserForm = New UserForm1`. This leaves the default instance alone, and the only running instance is the one you have explicitly set.