# Userform works despite Run-Time Error 91. What's going on?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am new to Userforms. I have created the following Userform which is called from a subroutine. The Userform picks up a range from a sheet and creates a corresponding number of textboxes and then checkboxes so as to allocate an original name with a new name.

[image: Userform]

The userform is created with the following:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Declare variables
    Dim txtBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim comBox As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim dist As Integer
    Dim dstArr As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    
    'Assign variables
    Set rng = Range("Missing_MAERSK")
    n = rng.Rows.Count
    dist = 5
    dstArr = Range("LU_Destination_Ports").Value
    
    'Loop to add textboxes
    For i = 1 To n
        Set txtBox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", Visible:=True)
        With txtBox
            .name = "txtBox" & i
            .Value = rng(i)
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 150
            .Left = 81
            .Top = 30 + dist
            .Font.Size = 10
        End With
        dist = dist + 20
    Next i
    
    'Loop to add list boxes
    dist = 5
    For j = 1 To n
        Set comBox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", Visible:=True)
        With comBox
            .name = "comBox" & j
            .List = dstArr
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 150
            .Left = 315
            .Top = 30 + dist
            .Font.Size = 10
        End With
        dist = dist + 20
    Next j
    
    'Show userform
    UserForm1.Show
    
End Sub
```

And then when the Replace Names button is clicked the following is ran:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'Close userform
    Unload UserForm1
    
    'This is the one
    Dim cmb As MSForms.ComboBox
'   Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Set rng = Range("MAERSK_Destin")
    Set rng2 = Range("Missing_MAERSK")
    n = rng2.Rows.Count
    
    'Loop
    For i = 1 To n
        Set txt = Me.Controls("txtBox" & i)
        Set cmb = Me.Controls("comBox" & i)
            If cmb.Value <> "" Then
                oldVal = txt.Value
                newVal = cmb.Value
                rng.Replace what:=oldVal, Replacement:=newVal
            End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Let's say I populate Bangkok to Bangkok BMT, I get the following:

[image]

I think the issue might be with the way I call the values in the Command_Button1_Click sub.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Don't you want to let the code finish before you unload the userform?

Comment: @Tim Williams my thinking was to do it with the form closed, since you can't see anything happening anyway. Could the unloaded userform be giving me the runtime error, since the userform is not visible?

Comment: Seems like you could just Hide the userform and then unload it when you're done?  Should be easy enough to try that.  FYI inside the userform it's safer to use `Me` to refer to the form instead of (eg) `UserForm1` - if you change the name you won't need to update the code.

Comment: I replaced ```Unload UserForm1``` with ```UserForm1.Hide``` and then once the loop runs I ran ```Unload UserForm1``` however had the same error message. Noted with using ```Me```

Comment: What happens when you hit "Debug" ?

Comment: Takes me to the sub where I call ```UserForm1.UserForm_Initialize```

Comment: To any specific line?

Comment: Nope, just to where its initialized

Comment: So you call `Initialize` directly?  Typically it runs automatically when a userform is displayed...

Comment: The sub is ran by button so once it does what it does (transfer and clean data) then the userform is initialized. Otherwise the userform is not displayed.

Comment: OK maybe check your VBA error handling option is set to "Break in class module" and see if that gives you more info.

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Strange how it still makes the replacements though despite spitting out the error

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas unless you're able to share the file.

Comment: Wish I could but its got client data. Appreciate all your help. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

According to this post: [Call UserForm_Initialize from Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725260/call-userform-initialize-from-module)

a UserForm should not be initialized from outside the userform.

I was calling `UserForm_Initialize()` from my sub, so to rectify this I replaced it with `UserForm1.Show`